# How to merge two data frames based on multiple columns?

Tags: r

I'm facing an issue with mapping gene symbols from one data frame (df2) to another (df1) in R, based on shared chromosome, start position, and end position columns. The startpos and endpos values in `df2` fall within the corresponding intervals in `df1`. Here are the structures of the two data frames.

**df1:**

```
structure(list(chr = c("1", "1", "1", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", 
"3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "4", "4", "4", "4", "4", "5", "5", 
"5", "5", "5", "5", "5", "5", "5", "6", "6", "6", "6", "6", "6", 
"6", "6", "7", "7", "7", "7", "7", "8", "8", "8", "8", "9", "9", 
"9", "9", "10", "10", "10", "11", "11", "11", "11", "11", "12", 
"12", "12", "12", "13", "13", "13", "13", "14", "14", "14", "14", 
"15", "16", "16", "16", "16", "17", "17", "17", "17", "17", "18", 
"18", "18", "18", "19", "19", "20", "20", "20", "21", "22", "X", 
"X"), startpos = c(3763769L, 30204151L, 145574212L, 41404L, 79025902L, 
84425655L, 97207752L, 195771938L, 319825L, 53724022L, 81670925L, 
84760199L, 130389220L, 167473864L, 4166887L, 9755086L, 36316146L, 
51848345L, 181522885L, 2788095L, 21585311L, 29848748L, 50371143L, 
72115891L, 94628989L, 107861719L, 142773060L, 167755050L, 549364L, 
8054180L, 36024843L, 44302628L, 63211948L, 93358143L, 106544755L, 
122454050L, 2712235L, 63876731L, 77122341L, 116695594L, 122013344L, 
219366L, 4787599L, 46635389L, 116942766L, 407227L, 61665918L, 
68540505L, 131604834L, 972645L, 42785641L, 58400552L, 4367675L, 
26537294L, 54591798L, 69295669L, 100356152L, 140964L, 38670828L, 
92531096L, 123835317L, 23009501L, 58528741L, 67228207L, 89361193L, 
20002158L, 42528760L, 85298658L, 106377432L, 19964897L, 1586202L, 
46618297L, 64982005L, 71230496L, 156366L, 27079757L, 29571810L, 
34959645L, 55315183L, 196829L, 20979714L, 42004300L, 67512592L, 
7117415L, 29606361L, 96321L, 31760029L, 46583816L, 14163568L, 
17424460L, 312451L, 155774775L), endpos = c(29516595L, 119471365L, 
248917151L, 75517955L, 80604356L, 89027732L, 191836667L, 239800120L, 
46460352L, 77635071L, 81670925L, 126852836L, 164163609L, 193626229L, 
5640434L, 32409374L, 48832879L, 177353681L, 186709835L, 16689924L, 
25911075L, 43609241L, 68226894L, 91476629L, 103201499L, 137946019L, 
163475701L, 175509230L, 8015924L, 31288236L, 41282856L, 56607197L, 
90312920L, 106234115L, 119269213L, 167948331L, 57200843L, 72629090L, 
113084740L, 118192084L, 159138060L, 3950145L, 42318418L, 112643523L, 
140300545L, 38615782L, 61666267L, 127344499L, 133402909L, 38378075L, 
54527809L, 131956064L, 23404921L, 50416083L, 63408895L, 96373497L, 
134381883L, 33426473L, 89523741L, 119857421L, 130036761L, 52820957L, 
61414933L, 85795917L, 110503806L, 39399442L, 81916397L, 100984697L, 
106874951L, 101828980L, 27483556L, 58920764L, 71203799L, 89562821L, 
21210841L, 29565997L, 34636381L, 51633681L, 81715184L, 13884567L, 
36653268L, 64232128L, 77436580L, 19679350L, 58478128L, 25320386L, 
46048325L, 64219694L, 42904255L, 49657199L, 2720458L, 155774775L
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -92L))
```

**df2:**

```
structure(list(hgnc_symbol = c("ERBB2", "PAK1"), chr = c("17", 
"11"), startpos = c(39687914L, 77322017L), endpos = c(39730426L, 
77474635L)), row.names = c(NA, -2L), class = "data.frame")
```

I have tried the `merge` function but it returned zero rows.

```
merge(df1, df2, by = c('chr', 'startpos', 'endpos'))
```

I'm wondering if there are alternative methods to achieve this mapping.

Thank you.

Comment: It's telling you that there is no match between all these columns.

Comment: could you also let us know what output are you expecting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what I tried:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)
setDT(df2)

# one way of merge
merged_df1 <- df1[df2, on = .(chr, startpos <= endpos, endpos >= startpos)]
merged_df1

# other way of merge
merged_df2 <- df2[df1, on = .(chr, startpos <= endpos, endpos >= startpos)]
merged_df2
```

You can change the conditions as per your need.

Please let me know if that works for you...